# How to pass my template into Django Userena signin/signup views

Tags: django, django-userena

I'm using django-userena-ce in my project. After configuring settings.py, i run my app and tried to sign up, but it calls its own template with form. How can i pass my own html template?
I tried this code:

```
    urlpatterns = [
          path('signup/', 'userena.views.signup', {'template_name': 'userena/register.html'}, name="signup"),
    ]
```

but it doesn't help. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have experience with userena-ce framework, but you can pass in the html template in your views.signup function using return render(). At least this is true in regular Django

Answer (score 0):

You do not define any view attributes in urlpatterns. It is just URLs definitions, nothing else.

To do what you ask for, create your own view which will be inheriting from `userena.views.signup`, and will overwrite `template_name` attribute. Something like this:

```
from userena.views import signup

class MySignUpView(signup):
    template_name = 'userena/register.html'
```

Then in urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
import MySignUpView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', MySignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```